# Vuetify - drag value from chip and drop to input doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop, vuetify.js

I have a couple of `v-chip` elements and a `form`. I'm trying to allow users to drag any chip and drop it anywhere in the form so the form `input` will have the chip value.

This is what I've done so far (simplified):

```
 <v-chip :draggable="true" @dragstart="draggedData='First Chip'">First Chip</v-chip>
 <v-text-field label="Droppable" v-model="input" @drop="input=draggedData"></v-text-field>
```

When the chip is dragged, it's value is stored in `draggedData`. After it's "dropped" to some input, the input should have the `draggedData` value but it doesn't happen.

Do you know what to do? Dragging works - dropping doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a need to use prevent default in `ondragover` event to stop blocking one element to drop to another element.

**Way 01:**

```js
<v-text-field
  label="Droppable"
  placeholder="Droppable"
  v-model="input"
  @drop="onDrop"
  @dragover.prevent
></v-text-field>
```

**Way 02:**

```js
<v-text-field
  label="Droppable"
  placeholder="Droppable"
  v-model="input"
  @drop="onDrop"
  @dragover="allowDrop"
></v-text-field>
```

```js
allowDrop(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
}
```

Here is the codesandbox for your reference.

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-poitras-w1qwp?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue